# Need (build?) files for eclipse on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, windows-7-x64

I've just downloaded Eclipse for C/C++ developers and I'm encountering issues with certain phrases and inclusions. Specifically, I can't perform `cout` or `cin`, and the lines `#include iostream` and `using namespace std` are errors according to the program.

Others have encountered these errors as well, and I understand that I'm missing some files dealing with the toolchain(?) I'm using. This is all very new to me and I don't know where to get the files I need to let the program work properly.

If anyone could direct me toward what I need or possibly explain what is going on I would greatly appreciate it. Again, I am running this under Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Can you post the specific errors it's spitting out?

Comment: What eclipse did you download?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm going to need you to enter Preferences in Window->Preferences. Then you are going to search for C/C++ and then New C/C++ Project Wizard. Over there you must look for the Toolchain your eclipse is using for you C/C++ projects.

The Toolchain is the Compiler, eclipse is just an IDE to help you develop. The compiler gets the job done. So if you have Visual C++, MinGW or CMake installed then maybe your paths are all wrong. If not maybe you need to install a distribution of those to allow Eclipse to build your projects.